# Download PDF after PayPal payment

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a WordPress site in which I have a PDF file and when user pays via PayPal pro, user downloads the file, Is their any automated facility that PayPal or WordPress provides in this regard or I have to do some real PHP coding in it?

I have used simple PayPal earlier, but downloading stuff after successful payment is something new for me.

Comment: @PedroLobito wouldn't that will be security wise weak ? since user can directly go to that url :)

Comment: @PedroLobito also the user pays via paypal pro not via simple paypal checkout.

Comment: You'll find everything you need  here : http://www.paysketch.com/setup-paypal-pdt/

Comment: @PedroLobito thanks but seems like we dont have wordpress plugin and we have to code it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend installing [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) along with [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/).

WooCommerce handles your product setup and delivery of digital goods upon purchase.  It comes with PayPal Standard built in, but "PayPal for WooCommerce" will add Express Checkout and Payments Pro for better PayPal integration and increased checkout rates.